# Can't stat app. after updating SpringBoot from 2.0.6.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.6.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR with a restful architecture
I updated the SpringBoot app. from 2.0.6.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE,

I have this config class:

```
public class DevApplicationConfig {

     @Autowired
     private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

     @Bean
     public AppErrorController appErrorController(){
         return new AppErrorController(errorAttributes);
     }

}
```

But after the change I got this error in Eclipse when I start the app:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'appErrorController', defined in class path resource [io/tdk/config/DevApplicationConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in file [/Users/nunet/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE/tdk/target/classes/io/tdk/web/controllers/AppErrorController.class] and overriding is disabled. 

@Controller
public class AppErrorController  implements ErrorController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppErrorController.class);
    /**
     * Error Attributes in the Application
     */
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    private final static String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Value("${systemadmin.email}")
    private String systemAdminEmail;

    @Value("${webmaster.email}")
    private String webMasterEmail;

    /**
     * Controller for the Error Controller
     * @param errorAttributes
     */
    public AppErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    /**
     * Supports the HTML Error View
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH, produces = "text/html")
    public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request, WebRequest webRequest) {

             SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
         mailMessage.setTo(systemAdminEmail);
         mailMessage.setSubject("System Error !");
         mailMessage.setText(getErrorAttributes(request, webRequest, true).toString());
         mailMessage.setFrom(webMasterEmail);

         emailService.sendGenericEmailMessage(mailMessage);



        return new ModelAndView(serverContextPath  +"/errors/error", getErrorAttributes(request, webRequest, true));
    }

    /**
     * Supports other formats like JSON, XML
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes( request, webRequest, true);
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(body, status);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the path of the error page.
     *
     * @return the error path
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }



    private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, WebRequest webRequest,
            boolean includeStackTrace) {

            return this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);

    }

    private HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if (statusCode != null) {
            try {
                return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does AppErrorController  class look like?

Comment: Remove the `@Bean` method. Spring Boot 2.1 prohibits (by default) to override beans. As you have `@Controller` an instance is already created and you override it with the one in the `@Bean` method. That isn't necessary and you can remove that (probably the whole `DevApplicationConfig` if that is all that is in there.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately I got the same error :-(

Comment: Remove AppErrorController appErrorController() method from DevApplicationConfig. You don't need it. @Controller method is sufficient. Just make sure the package is scanned by Spring. Add @ComponentScan("<your root package>") in Spring boot main class.

Comment: @Debopam, please convert to asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line to the `applicaton.propertie`s file

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: While this will stop the error from occurring, it typically won't fix the underlying problem. IMO, a better solution is to adjust the application's configuration so that the bean is no longer overridden.

Answer (score 4):

A change was made in Spring Boot 2.1 to disable bean overriding by default. This was done to make it easier to identify and correct accidental overriding of a bean. An accidental override is what appears to be happening here.

`AppErrorController` is annotated with `@Controller` which makes in a `@Component` and it appears to be in a package that's covered by component scanning. When component scanning encounters `AppErrorController` it defines a bean named `appErrorController`.

`DevApplicationConfig` is then processed. It contains a `@Bean` method that defines a bean named `appErrorController`:

```
 @Bean
 public AppErrorController appErrorController(){
     return new AppErrorController(errorAttributes);
 }
```

In Spring Boot 2.0 and earlier, this would result in the `AppErrorController` bean defined via component scanning being overridden by the bean defined in `DevApplicationConfig`. If you look closely at the logs when you start your application with Spring Boot 2.0.x, you should see that an info message has been logged for the overridden bean. In Spring Boot 2.1 it results in a failure due to bean overriding being disabled by default.

To fix the problem, remove the `appErrorController` `@Bean` method from `DevApplicationConfig`. This allows the definition that's generated by component scanning to be used. I would recommend making the same change in a Spring Boot 2.0 and earlier application. Removing unnecessary override makes application startup a little more efficient and avoids cluttering your application's logs with info messages about beans being overridden.

If you need to be able to override a bean in Spring Boot 2.1, you can restore 2.0's behaviour by setting a property:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I would only recommend doing this if you're in the unusual situation where the override is deliberate and there's no easy way to rework the configuration so that it does not occur.